# Button labels missing from security confirmation for installer

Tags: macos, mac

When trying to install software and prompted for username and password, button labels are missing as well as the stored username:

[image: Installer security alert]

[image: console output]

Comment: Which version of OS X are you running? And which piece of software are you trying to install? Or does this happen with all installers?

Comment: 10.8, happens with all installers.

Comment: Just added a screenshot of the console output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a problem with the font cache on your Mac. You can reset the font cache on Mountain Lion with the following steps.

1. Open Terminal and run this command: `sudo atsutil databases -remove`
2. Reboot immediately